# Recursively add all .jpg files to their own html element using find

Tags: linux

I was curious if it is possible to recursively find all `*.jpg` file types in a given directory then output them inside of their own `<img src="">` tag to a new *.html* document while still keeping their original filenames using Linux.

An example of what I mean would be:

```
    find . -name "*.jpg" to >> new file
```

Listed as

```
    <img src="image1".jpg>
    <img src="image2".jpg>
    <img src="image3".jpg>
    // ...and so on
```

Currently I have tried both of these commands but am not seeing what is missing.

```
    for %i in (*.jpg) do echo ^<img src="%i" /^> >> newfile.html

    find . -name ‘.jpg’ -exec mv ‘*.jpg’ ‘^<img src=“*.jpg”>^’ \;
```

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

The following command should do the job.

`find . -name "*.jpg" -exec echo  '<img src="{}">' \; > index.html`

It is similar to your `find . -name ‘.jpg’ -exec mv ‘*.jpg’ ‘^<img src=“*.jpg”>^’ \;` but

1. `-name '.jpg'` which will only find file with name .jpg not all the file with suffix .jpg
2. `-exec mv` will attempt to move the file not echo the statement

This command have several issues.
`for %i in (*.jpg) do echo ^<img src="%i" /^> >> newfile.html`

1. Fist the for block syntax is incorrect. This is the correct one.`for i in *.jpg; do command;done`
2. Second in shell script we use $i in stead of %i to use the variable.
3. Lastly < and > is used for redirection in bash so you should quote your echo argument.
4. Finally you would have
   `for i in *.jpg;do echo "<img src=\"$i\">";done`
5. Still this command wouldn't recursively find the jpeg file only on you current directory